# long-title posts do not want published

Tags: posts, wp-query, filters, title, wp-title

long title posts do not want published, when I click on published (not function) always on draft.

**For example:**

The title 'Le général sorti un badge et se dirigea vers l’une des portes entourées de peinture jaune Il glissa le badge dans la fente située à droite '.

[image: image before and after click published]

Comment: It works fine here, I managed to save a draft with the title `Le général sorti un badge et se dirigea vers l’une des portes entourées de peinture jaune Il glissa le badge dans la fente située à droite` just fine, when you say it doesn't work, can you be more specific? JS errors? WSOD? PHP fatal errors? HTTP 500? The post saves but the title is unchanged? I can't replicate this in vanilla WP

Comment: I guess the orange bar you've highlighted is an empty error message that you're getting? Can you inspect the page to see if there are any clues to where it came from, e.g. CSS classes or text fragments? (I'd guess not.) Failing that, anything in the PHP logs which might indicate why it's showing an empty bar, e.g. error fetching text?